# Changing a value in a dictionary to be imported from a list and cycle through, with urllib2

Tags: python, dictionary, urllib2

I am using Python 2.7, and attempting to script a form to run through multiple queries. The value of 'name1place1' needs to cycle through several queries, such as name1place2, name2place3, etc. I have all of the sites in a text file and will insert them as strings. I want to run this as a single script and it will go through all of the sites at once. I think a for loop needs to be involved.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'someurl.php'
values = {'site' : 'name1place1', 'size' : '8'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

Thanks for helping, this probably isn't too difficult but I am still learning!

Comment: Is your question: how do I fill the `values` dictionary with nameXplaceX where X goes from 1 to N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do something like:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'someurl.php'
values = {'site' : 'name1place1', 'size' : '8'}

sites_file = 'path/to/sites_file'
with open(sites_file, 'r') as sites:
    for site_value in sites: # This pulls each line out the file

        # Remove trailing whitespace or '\n' from site and replace value in dict
        values['site'] = site_value.rstrip() 
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        the_page = response.read()
        print the_page
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code a little bit, but it works! It queries through my entire list and runs the function! I'd upvote but I dont have enough rep.